# Itunesconnect stuck on "This Field is Required"

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I've submitted a new app to itunesconnect - which got rejected because of a metadata issue. I fixed the metadata issue and replied to them in the resolution centre. However, I was not sure whether I need to press "Submit for Review" again on the app page (since they do not really specify). So, I went to go press it just for in case. It does not want to trigger and gives an error "This field is required" - with NO indication of what it actually wants?

Please, does anyone have a suggestion on how to fix this. I have already set the age rating, privacy policy etc. It has screenshots and a binary file. As far as I can see, it should be good to go. At this stage, it looks like they are just trying to make life difficult.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

OK, so after scrambling around and changing random fields, I inserted a value for "Copy Right" and that seemed to work. After I submitted though, it immediately cleared that field from the entry I had put in? So, not sure what that is all about. Hopefully this helps someone else too.